# Retrieving substring using string::reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, string

A substring denoted by two std::string::reverse_iterators, how can I copy them out and assign to a new string with normal sequence, not reversely?

One senario may be: A string of "Hello world-John", probe from tail and meet '-' using:

```
      std::string::reverse_iterator rIter
         = std::find(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), isDelimiterFunc);
```

And the rIter is pointing at '-'.
I want to get the "John" out, but if I do:

```
  std::string out(str.rbegin(), rIter - 1);
```

I will got "nhoj".

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [string::rfind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) to solve that problem.

```
std::string f;
auto pos = f.rfind("-");
std::string f2= f.substr(pos);
```

Otherwise you can obtain the underlying `iterator` of a `reverse_iterator` through the `base()` member function and it returns an off-by-one iterator.

Comment: thanks for your concern pmr, but I cannot do if the delimter is a char set. Lets focus on using string::reverse_iterator.

Comment: @Lyn, yes you can using [`std::string::find_last_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of).

Comment: @hmjd, thanks! Was confused with find/rfind. I`ll try it right now,

Comment: The member function is called `base()`, and will surprise everyone by returning an iterator that is off by one. See [reverse_iterator::base()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10sbbf0k(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks, i got confused somehow.

Answer (score 2):

As requested...

Following the lead of @pmr's answer which provides a simpler approach, to search for one of multiple characters in `std::string` you can use [`std::string::find_last_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of):

```
std::string str("Hello world-John");
const size_t idx = str.find_last_of("-x!@~");
if (std::string::npos != idx)
{
    std::cout << str.substr(idx+1) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hmjd, your help resolved my real problem. After cool down, I found myself still curious about the reverse_iterator way. I`ve already upvoted you, if there is no answer, I`ll accept you. Hope you will understand... again thanks!